# Existence of maximal totally ramified extensions of an arbitrary CDVF

Tags: fields, valuation-theory, nt.number-theory

Let $K$ be a complete, discretely valued field with (let's say) perfect residue field $k$.  We have a unique maximal unramified extension $K^{unr}$ of $K$ and a unique maximal tamely ramified extension $K^{tame}$ of $K$ and hence short exact sequences

$1 \rightarrow Gal(K^{sep}/K^{unr}) \rightarrow Gal(K^{sep}/K) \rightarrow Gal(K^{unr}/K) \rightarrow 1$

and

$1 \rightarrow Gal(K^{tame}/K^{unr}) \rightarrow Gal(K^{tame}/K) \rightarrow Gal(K^{unr}/K) \rightarrow 1$.

In the second case, the normal subgroup is abelian and I know exactly what the action of the quotient on it is: the tame cyclotomic character.  Therefore if it splits, I know its structure as an explicit semidirect product.

In the most famous case, $k$ is finite, so $Gal(K^{unr}/K) = Gal(k^{sep}/k) \cong \widehat{\mathbb{Z}}$ is a projective profinite group, so both sequences certainly split.  This means that I (and lots of other people) do know the structure of the tame Galois group explicitly: it is $\prod_{\ell \neq p} \mathbb{Z}_{\ell}(1) \rtimes \widehat{\mathbb{Z}}$.  Similarly the first sequence splits so there is a totally ramified extension $L/K$ such that $K^{sep}/L$ is unramified.  Moreover, this is a very useful fact: it follows for instance that any abelian variety over $K$ with potentially good reduction acquires good reduction over a totally ramified base extension.

What is known in general?  We have $Gal(K^{unr}/K) = Gal(k^{sep}/k)$, but if $k$ is almost anything else reasonable -- e.g. a local or global field, or the function field of a variety -- then its absolute Galois group certainly will not be projective.  What is known about the splitting of these two short exact sequences in general, and especially about the class $\eta \in H^2(Gal(K^{unr}/K),Gal(K^{tame}/K^{unr}))$ defined by the second sequence?  Is there information on how the analogues of the above results do / do not work out if these sequences do not split?

Comment: Pete, as for the good reduction of abelian variety, you mean an abelian variety with good reduction over a *tamely ramified* extension ? Then it is always true that the a.v. has good reduction over a totally ramified extension. You just take any totally ramified extension $L/K$ of the right degree. Then the abelian variety has good reduction over an étale extension of $L$, so it already has good reduction over $L$ (because the Néron model commutes with étale base change). This holds also for semi-abelian reduction, and $K$ is any disc. val. field. No idea about the splitting.

Comment: Qing: no I'm not assuming that the reduction becomes good over a tamely ramified extension.  The point is that this is using the splitting of the sequence.  I have no reason to think it is true in general....

Comment: The 2nd sequence always splits (similar to Q. Liu's comment). Take a "non-Galois Kummer extension" $K'/K$ generated by a compatible system of $e$th roots of a fixed uniformizer $\pi$ as $e$ varies through all integers $\ge 1$ not divisible by residue char.  This is totally tame, and any tame finite $L/K$ is generated over an unram. subextension by $e$th root of $u \pi$ where $u$ is unit of that unram. subextension. So $LK'/K'$ is generated by an $e$th root of a unit in an "unramified" extension of $K'$.  That is, $K^{\rm{tame}}$ is compositum of linearly disjoint $K'/K$ and $K^{\rm{un}}/K$. 

Comment: You could also consider a third exact sequence $1 \rightarrow Gal(K^{sep}/K^{tame}) \rightarrow Gal(K^{sep}/K) \rightarrow Gal(K^{tame}/K) \rightarrow 1$, and ask for the existence of a maximal totally and wildly ramified extension.  Of course this is intersting only when the residual characteristic is $\neq0$.

Answer (score -1):

The second sequence always split.  This is proved in a paper by Kuhlmann, Pank, and
Roquette, manuscripta mathematica 55 (1986), 39-77.